# How to use ML in asset optimisation / valuation - for Gas Trading?

Tags: machine-learning, trading

All,
I am new to Machine Learning as well as to Python programming. 
I am working on – Asset Optimization

---

### Gas Trading – Swing Contract.

Swing Contract – A buyer must select best 90 days out of 365 days where he can make the maximum profit.
**Note:** The forecast/data available for the gas trading comes from the traders and changes every day.

Here is the sample data.

[image]

Days are not continuous and the average price is available for month ahead, year ahead, season ahead and quarter ahead

---

I have built python code, which predicts the price and selects the top 90 from the historical data.

But the algorithm is not using any ML techniques to do so.

I was just wondering if someone has worked on similar problems to share some insights or relevant link to look for addition information.

Thanks,
Ajit

Comment: For me the question seems way to broad for stackoverflow (think of regression, time series method, neural networks etc. to tackle this problem), maybe it fits better in [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Btw, the algorithm you described is a ML-algorithm, though it will perform probably very poorly.

Comment: Thanks. Will post this problem in crossvalidated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a clustering problem. Try learning about K-means clustering.

Comment: I am quite not sure how it can clustering problem. Can you please help me by sharing your understanding ?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Finding the best 90 days out of 365 days does not intuitively sound like a classification problem. If I were you, I would try to think in terms of anomaly detection. Here the anomaly will be the best days.

Think on this.